# What size needle should I use with 210d Dyneema X Gridstop when sewing my own pack?

Tags: diy, ultralight

I'm new to sewing and new to pack-making.  Trying to build a lightweight pannier, since most panniers are made out of heavy cordura.  I've ordered 2 yards of a  210d Dyneema X Gridstop; (specs here: [Materials used in ZPacks Gear](http://www.zpacks.com/materials.shtml)) and am wondering what type of needle/needle size I should use for sewing it.

Comment: Personally I would use 100/16 for this project.

Answer (score 5):

The needle size depends on the size of the thread.

With that material, you would possibly use MARA 50 (Tex 60) to get strong seams, but you can also use a Tex 40, which is already plenty strong. I would not recommend a smaller thread.

I usually use the following needles for thread size:

- Tex 30: needle 70/10
- Tex 40: needle 80/12
- Tex 60: needle 90/14 or 100/16 if you have many layer to get through